# Can I get the coordinates of country borders from Google Maps?

Tags: coordinate-system, google-maps, google-earth

I need to get the coordinates of a country's border (e.g., Iraq) from Google Maps. How can I do that?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to GIS.se - could you click 'edit' and explain more about what you want to do? Do you want the coordinates of points?

Comment: yes .i need to get the coordinates located on the borders in google maps .

Comment: The image has no "black border." Please clarify that and, when you edit your question, explain what form you want the coordinates in and whether you want to obtain them interactively or with a program.

Comment: The image does have a black border, it's the border of Iraq, so perhaps the question is asking how to get the coordinates of the Iraq border...

Comment: You really can't get out data from Google maps. you will find more success getting data from other sources like http://www.naturalearthdata.com/

Comment: thanks to all for replying ..i get the data from using archgis as in this : http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90927/how-to-get-x-y-coordinates-of-all-vertices-from-polygon-in-shapefile-as-excel-sp

Comment: This is now a useful question, esp. after my edits :-), and with @DevdattaTengshe's comment converted into an answer, should be re-opened.

Comment: Thanks for the very useful answer @Matt N.
can i ask a follow up question... how do we know what kind of collections are availble ? e.g. "'USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017'" in your answer? Also, Can I export boundaries of the all the countries?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Get the x,y coordinates of the boundaries of countries from the following website [**Natural Earth**](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/) (thanks, Devdatta Tengshe) which has more accurate data than others I've tried. Then use ArcGIS 10.2 to open the map shape file and select the boundaries you need. Go to data management tools --features-- features vertices to points and open the generated table. Add two new fields (lat, long) to the table. (I use geometry calculations.) Export the table to get the desired data.

Answer (score 2):

I use GADM / DIVA-GIS's downloads:

- http://www.gadm.org/country
- http://diva-gis.org/gdata

Also provides other basic data types; administrative areas, inland water, roads, rail, elevation, land cover, population, monthly climate, gazette (cities etc)...in various vector/raster formats. All can be used in QGIS.

Of course the OpenStreetMap has the data included but it's not a simple thing to extract this information directly.

Comment: Sadly none of the links above work anymore 

Answer (score 0):

You can also get country border data using [Google Earth Engine](https://earthengine.google.com/). Here's a script that would do this:

```
// Get vector data for various types of borders.
var worldBorders = ee.FeatureCollection( 'USDOS/LSIB_SIMPLE/2017' );

// Create a filter that specifies Iraq's borders.
var iraqFilter = ee.Filter.eq( 'country_na', 'Iraq' );

// Filter the global data to get only Iraq.
var iraqRegion = worldBorders.filter( iraqFilter );

// Export Iraq's borders as a KML file.
Export.table.toDrive(
  {
    collection: iraqRegion,
    description:'iraqBorderData',
    fileFormat: 'KML'
  }
);
```

By running the script and exporting the data as a KML file, you could [view it in Google Maps](https://www.igismap.com/upload-kml-file-google-map/) and [Google Earth](https://support.google.com/earth/answer/7365595?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop). The KML file will be saved to your Google Drive. If you wanted to first view it in Earth Engine, you could also include the following code:

```
// Rasterize the global data for viewing in Earth Engine.
var worldBordersImage = ee.Image().paint( worldBorders, 0, 7 );

// Clip the global data to Iraq.
var iraqBordersImage = worldBordersImage.clip( iraqRegion );

// View Iraq's borders on Earth Engine's map.
Map.addLayer( iraqBordersImage, { palette: ['black'] }, 'Iraq Border' );
Map.setCenter( 43.46, 33.134 );
Map.setZoom( 6 );
```